# Mergear dados de coluna JSON PostgreSQL ao realizar UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

O cenário é o seguinte, possuo uma coluna do tipo JSONB em meu banco em que uma estrutura em JSON é salva.

O que eu preciso é que quando essa estrutura seja atualizada, ele atualize somente as chaves que estiverem sido solicitadas para atualizar e mantenha as já existentes. Se você der um update comum nesse tipo de coluna ele apenas substitui os dados antigos pelos novos, entretanto eu preciso realizar um MERGE.

Em alguns outros cenários do código eu tenho usado a seguinte estrutura:

```
update tabela set coluna=(coluna || (jsonDeEntrada)::jsonb);
```

Funciona para os casos que tinha até hoje, mas minha nova estrutura JSON tem mais ou menos essa organização:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "key1.1": {
      "key": "valor",
      "key": "valor"
    },
    "key1.2": {}
  },
  "key2": {
    "key2.1": {
      "key": "valor",
      "key": "valor"
    },
    "key2.2": {}
  },
  "key3": {
    "key": "valor",
    "key": "valor",
    "key": "valor"
  }
}
```

Em determinados cenários **eu preciso alterar somente uma das chaves dentro da `key1.1`**, nesse caso precisaria somente **atualizar o valor dela e manter as outras**, mas o que é feito (mesmo utilizando quela estrutura de MERGE que coloquei ali em cima) é que ele substitui todo o conteúdo da `key1.1` pelo novo JSON passado, no caso, deletando as outras chaves que não foram mencionadas no UPDATE.

Por acaso existe alguma maneira eficaz de mergear direto pelo PostgreSQL, ou realmente vou precisar criar sempre o objeto na mesma estrutura e incluir os dados que não desejo alterar também, para substituir o JSON inteiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a solução para o meu problema.

Para realizar o merge de alguma chave do JSON que esteja após o 1º nível o `operador de concatenação` '`||`' não serve, ele consegue fazer o merge apenas de chaves no primeiro nível, após isso ele realiza sobreposição.

Para poder realizar o merge de uma sub-chave específica independente do nível utilizei a função `jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb[, create_missing boolean])`.

Os 4 parâmetros (em ordem) representam:

1. O **JSON** no qual você **estará realizando uma alteração** (nome da minha coluna no banco)
2. O **caminho** até a chave **na qual desejo realizar alterações** no JSON interno dela
3. O **JSON que deve ser inserido** no local especificado no segundo parâmetro
4. Booleano que indica se você deseja sobrescrever a alteração (false) ou inserir a alteração junto ao que já possui (true).

Conforme a arquitetura do JSON da pergunta, para realizar o merge do conteúdo dentro da `key1.1`, a estrutura ficará da seguinte forma:

```
update tabela set colunaJSON = jsonb_set(colunaJSON,'{key1,key1.1}',colunaJSON->'key1'->'key1.1' || '{"chave1": "valor", "chave3": "valor}',false);
```

Vejam que da mesma forma, ainda tive que utilizar o operador `||` para realizar o merge das informações. Caso o mesmo não seja utilizado as informações serão reescritas.